# How do I prevent disk brakes from squeaking in the rain?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, noise, rain

When I got my new bike with disk brakes, I thought that they would perform much better in the rain.  While this is true, they still squeak quite loud in wet conditions, which is quite annoying.  Is there a certain type of disk brake or brake pads which perform better in the rain and aren't so loud?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way that I've found to get them to stop squeaking is to burn the water off.  Big steep hill and stop at the bottom.

As for performance, I don't notice any difference in the feel of my BB7's in the wet vs. the dry after a couple seconds of use.  Even in rain puddles up to the bottom bracket.

Answer (score 11):

I eventually learned to live with it. I've tried different brake pads, and even ones that claim to be less noisy. No difference.

Really what we're talking about is the same thing behind rubbing a finger on a wine glass, or scratching chalk across a blackboard. "Slip-stick motion". What really makes it loud, I think, is the high tension bicycle wheel.

I agree... it's really embarassing, especially when pulling up to a stop. Everyone around thinks some train is stopping haha, or they think your brakes don't work. Quite the contrary, they are working pretty good actually!!!

Comment: I like that sound. Very nice side effect. And all the people around immediately realize that I'm a serious man.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [sanding your rotors](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Tech-Tuesday-Silence-That-Squeaky-Disc-Brake-2011.html)?

I realize that's for dry-squeals, but having a more abrasive surface may reduce wet noise as well, and even if not it should decrease the time it takes to burn off the water.